# dplyr join on Mysql data with diacriticals

Tags: mysql, r, dplyr

I'm not even sure how to formulate a search for this.

In my MySQL data,

`SELECT "Anaïs" = "Anais"`

yields "1". The table is utf8mb4 encoded, with general_ci collation. (And I have almost no idea what any of that actually means.) So in my database, those two strings are equivalent.

But I'm pulling that data into an R script, and using dplyr join to match it to a different table/data frame. And in R:

`"Anaïs" == "Anais"`

yields "FALSE".

Also, MySQL is case-insensitive, but in R (DBI??), the joins are case sensitive. (There are a bunch of typos in my raw data where things are accidentally not capitalized, like Depaul and DePaul, for example.)

What's the best way to fix this issue?

THANKS.

Answer (score 0):

From `stringi` `stri_trans_general` convert the Latin to ASCII

```
library(stringi)
stri_trans_general('Anaïs','Latin-ASCII')=='Anais'
[1] TRUE
```

For the upper cass, using `toupper`

Comment: Thanks Wen. What about doing it on the SQL side? I'd rather have the database know that ï != I and that A !=a.